# Private method in Typescript definitions(React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is just a general question which has been bothering me for sometime.

I have a React component that has some methods both private and public.
Lets assume I have a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CRComponent } from '../CRComponent';

export interface Props {
  className?: string;
  type?: string;
}

class AlertItem extends CRComponent<Props> {
  public render() {
    return (
      ///// Some render
    );
  }

  private getClassNames() {
    ///some logic
  }

  private mapAlertTypeIcon() {
    ///Some logic
  }
}

export default AlertItem;
```

When I generate a typescript definition file the following file gets generated:

```
import { CRComponent } from '../CRComponent';
interface Props {
  className?: string;
}
declare class AlertItem extends CRComponent<Props> {
  private getClassNames;
  private mapAlertTypeIcon;
  public render(): JSX.Element;
}
export default AlertItem;
```

I purposefully removed the prop `type` from the .d.ts file so that the user cannot use it as it is internal.

Now when I publish this .d.ts file all the member methods are published in .d.ts file including private. For this class the methods are relatively less. Suppose I have a big component then the number of private methods might be huge.

Now a component library will have lots of such component.

When I publish these a major size of the package is because of these files. So my question is that whether it is necessary to keep private members in the .d.ts files or can I just ignore them as the user will not have access to them anyway?

I tried finding answers but could not find one. So a help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A private method changes whether you can create a substitutable type, for example the declaration of `Example` prevents a type match with our concrete class (whether or not we add a private identity member!)

```
declare class Example {
    private identity: string;
    public doSomething(): string;
}

class ConcreteExample {
    private identity: string = 'id';

    doSomething() { 
        return 'done';
    }
}

function passMeExample(input: Example) {

}

// ConcreteExample is not allowable!
passMeExample(new ConcreteExample());
```

If you remove the private members, it changes the behaviour of the type checking:

```
declare class Example {
    public doSomething(): string;
}

class ConcreteExample {
    private identity: string = 'id';

    doSomething() { 
        return 'done';
    }
}

function passMeExample(input: Example) {

}

// OK!
passMeExample(new ConcreteExample());
```

So it is important to bear in mind that there is a difference in behaviour if you remove those private members. The classes will not act as they would if they were included.

Comment: Is this because ConcreteExample does not have the identical name Example?

Comment: TypeScript is structurally typed, not nominally typed, but you'll find that structures don't match if a private member is added to the target type (it's not a problem if a private member is added to the supplied type).